# Laplace transform $ \mathscr{L} \left( \int_0^t \frac{e^{-\tau}-1}{\tau}d\tau \right) $

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Can anyone give me a hint to solve

$$
\mathscr{L}  \left( \int_0^t \frac{e^{-\tau}-1}{\tau}d\tau \right)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try finding the laplace transform of this function:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{e^{-t} -1}{t}
\end{equation*}

Using the rule:

\begin{equation*}
L\left(\frac{f( t)}{t}\right) =\int ^{\infty }_{s} g( s)
\end{equation*}
where

\begin{equation*}
L( f( t)) =g( s)
\end{equation*}
then try using the rule

\begin{equation*}
L\left(\int ^{t}_{0} f( t) dt\right) =\frac{g( s)}{s}
\end{equation*}
I thin this should lead you where you want.